# Tornado template loader from string - Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, tornado

I am deploying a tornado server on Heroku. I currently load templates from files the standard way. I would like to load them from a database field and not from a file.

How do I do that the clean way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Template](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/template.py#L200) instead of [Loader](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/template.py#L338).

It will be simple as:

```
from tornado.template import Template
t = Template(my_template_string_from_database)
r = t.generate(key=value) #as we do in loader
```

Example not checked, but think this way. And don't be afraid of tornado code - it's easy to read it.